# NoSuchBufferException in netty 4.0, questions about ChannelOutboundMessageHandler constructs

Tags: netty

I think I am not understanding the intention of some of the different classes.

So I have a simple pipeline, essentially it takes the Top level objects which serialize via a custom method (hadoop writables), then attempts to turn these to ByteBufs and then send them.  So I implemented an OutboundFrameHandler, which takes the Message Object, then attempts to serialize the simple framing and then sends it upstream.  Here is the implementation:

```
public class OutboundFrameHandler extends MessageToByteEncoder<MsgType> {

  public void encode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MsgType msg, ByteBuf out) throw Exception {
     byte[] data = ...; // custom serialization mechanism

     out.writeInt(data.length + 4);
     out.writeInt(msg.callId);
     out.writeBytes(data);
  }
 }
```

At runtime I get this:

WARNING: An exceptionCaught() event was fired, and it reached at the end of the pipeline.  It usually means the last inbound handler in the pipeline did not handle the exception.
io.netty.channel.NoSuchBufferException: Could not find a suitable destination buffer.  Double-check if the pipeline is configured correctly and its handlers works as expected.

I looked at the example source code, and one thing I noticed is the "encoding" codecs appear to be more like so:
public class StringEncoder extends MessageToMessageEncoder {}

and the 'encode' method creates the ByteBuf.

But I ALSO noticed that ProtobufVarint32LengthFieldPrepender extends MessageToByteEncoder and uses the ByteBuf out argument.  I looked at the source code, and I'm not really sure HOW that 'out' becomes set to something.  It is obtained in MessageToByteEncoder 'flush' by calling ctx.nextOutboundByteBuffer() but it's not clear to me HOW this is working.  Looking at how this comes about, it looks like this is set during init and one of the handlers needs to return a ByteBuf from newOutboundBuffer.

Doing backwards analysis, it appears that the only subclass that returns a ByteBuf from newOutboundBuffer() is ChannelOutboundByteHandlerAdapter. And there are few subclasses of that.

So looking at the localtime example, it's not clear to me how ProtobufVarin32LengthFieldPrepender actually *WORKS*.  It also appears that while I used MessageToByteEncoder what I REALLY want is MessageToMessageEncoder

Summary questions:
- when would one use a MessageToByteEncoder
- how does a encoder based on MessageToByteEncoder get a valid outbound buf when no handlers in the pipeline seem to return a ByteBuf from newOutboundBuffer?

** ANSWERING MYSELF **

Turns out that (a) I hadnt enqueued the correct message type! and (b) I dove and found out about HeadHandler which is the ByteBuf generator of "last resort" it seems.  All is well now.